# how can I set edit box values (in react application) by clicking on a link in an email?

Tags: reactjs, hyperlink, react-props, react-state

I am new to react programming, and I have no idea how to set "incoming data" from a hyperlink on a web page when a user clicks a link an email.

In other words, I get an email with a link in it... I click on the link, that link takes me to a web page and populates two edit boxes with data (from the link).

I know how to code up the back end api that would accept data in api formate, for example in the 'discounts.js' api file, I could do this:

```
router.post('/discounts/:userCode/discount/:discountCode'
```

**BUT** what I want to do is send this link via email, have the user click the link and have the resulting page populated with data.

Here is an example link

```
    example.com/discountPage/:snvpsnan8zosfluawpcn50ycdipa6rrqlym/code/:sdfiedgmmkfzuky2f6grds
```

So after the user clicks the link, the REACT web page edit boxes should look like this:

[image: web page populated with data from link]

given the following react (partial) component:

```
class discountPage extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      userCode: '',
      discountCode: ''
      errors: {}
    };

    this.onChange = this.onChange.bind(this);
    this.onSubmit = this.onSubmit.bind(this);
  }

  onChange(e) {
    this.setState({ [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }
```

I am thinking I might be able to set the data in the componentDidMount - but really unsure of where the data from link comes from and how it gets set?

Does it come from the props ?

```
  componentDidMount() {

    console.log('Register : componentDidMount ');

    this.setState({'userCode': this.props.userCode });
    this.setState({'discountCode': this.props.discountCode });
  }
```

**UPDATE**

Based on Pinaka30's response... I did some searching and found this:

https://www.webdeveloperpal.com/2018/02/21/react-router-get-url-params/

```
import queryString from 'query-string';

class UserComponent extends React.Component{
 render(){
  // url is 'https://www.example.com/user?id=123&type=4';
  let url = this.props.location.search;
  let params = queryString.parse(url);
  console.log(params);
  // The result will be like below
  // { id: 123, type: 4 }
  // other code
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There can be many methods, and the one I am listing might not be the best, but it will definitely give you desired results.
Since you are clicking a link and then being redirected to a new page with your form, the request will be a GET request. As we know, the parameters are visible in the url in case of a GET request. So what you can do is retrieve userCode and DiscountCode from the url itself.

```
componentDidMount(){
  var url = window.location.href;  //Gives you the complete url
  temp = url.split(""); //Split the url to retrieve both parameters according to your format
  this.setState({
    userCode: temp[0],
    discountCode: temp[1]
  });
}
```

In your render method, use state as the value

```
<input id="userCode" value={this.state.userCode} />
<input id="discountCode" value={this.state.discountCode} />
```

So as soon as your page loads and the component renders, componentDidMount will get called and update the states which will be reflected in your input boxes. Just split the url carefully. I didn't write that line completely because i didn't know the format.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6819920/pinaka30  the link is being clicked from some email ... does that make a difference?  or is the URL the same regardless of the origin?

Comment: The url will remain the same

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/6819920/pinaka30 : thanks.. how do I setup the Route to accept the parameters now?  I have this:  <Route exact path="/verify:id" component={Verify} />  but that is not picking up the parameters ... ???  link is this: http://localhost:3000/verify?id=hlzga6lvepckt6b1bqrxibnqn6vjyklfaut

Comment: Use `this.props.match.params.id` in your Verify component. Find out more about react router paths here : [URL Params](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/url-params) and [Match keyword](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/match)